# How to trigger inactive jobs at Jenkins (using ScriptTrigger Plugin and Groovy)?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, triggers

We have some hundred projects configured at Jenkins and we like to trigger inactive jobs to check whether they are still ok. (e.g. to check whether the dependency ranges are ok and not causing failures if a new dependency version appears)

By “inactive” I mean jobs which are currently not under development and thus without commits. (So SCM-trigger won’t work…)

The current solution is to build all Jobs at the night to Monday ;) – But this produces high load on Jenkins and also causes some trouble during massively hot deployment during build time…

So the idea is to use [ScriptTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScriptTrigger+Plugin) and trigger builds only if the last build is some time ago (e.g. one week).

We have a Groovy script showing which jobs are inactive:

```
def now = Calendar.instance.time.time;

for (item in Hudson.instance.items) { 
    def days = (now - item.getLastBuild().time.time) / 86400000;
    def inactive = days > 7;

    println(item.toString() + "\t" + days + "\t" + inactive);
}
```

This script runs perfectly at Jenkins Script Console.

But we don’t know how to adopt it to make it work with ScriptTrigger Plugin because we don’t know how to access the job. – Variable `item` in this case…

We have tried:

```
//println(job);
//println(module);
//println(lastBuild);
//println(project);
```

So how to access the job and lastBuild?

Or is there a better way to trigger (only) jobs without commits?